# Xcode 11 IB UI - How to revert constraints grouping settings to Xcode 10 way

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint, user-experience, xcode11

Starting with Xcode 11 the IB [Interface Builder] UI for constraints is grouped into vertical and horizontal categories instead of as before when constraints between children views were in a separate group and constraints which the view had with other siblings or parents were in a separate group.

Xcode 11:

[image]

Xcode 10 and prior:

[image]

This is extremely hard to navigate for me especially in very complex constraint hierarchies and especially when not all the views have identifiable names associated with them. You end up seeing view -> view when actually that's the relationship with the child which does matter considerably less in most of the cases I'm solving.

Is it possible to revert the Xcode 11 IB UI to the same way it was in Xcode 10?